# Mount 360 degree rotator with camera using 2 pins (Power line and Gnd)

Tags: camera

I am designing a rotator circuit which consists of a 5v stepper motor[enter link description here](https://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/5V-100-1-Geared-Miniature-Small-Stepper-Motor-/281737009862?_mwBanner=1) and 5v DRV8834 driver IC[enter link description here](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J617/drv8834.pdf). The driver IC got 1 pins which is a step to control the motor. The problem/question is that only a two lines come from the camera top section. The camera top section runs at 12V. Is that possible to use the same 12V line to toggle as a 5V step pulse as well? The idea is as soon as the bottom section is connected to the top section, the Intelligent circuit should recognize whether the rotator is receiving 12V power or 5V step signal. If it is 12V then the system stays on and shouldn't consume current as well doesn't harm the motor. When it receives 5V step signal it goes through the 5V buck regulator (only if needed?) and supply the voltage to the motor and turns on the rotator. Is that possible to connect? I have attached the rough block diagram. Please let me know your ideas.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ8d5p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My actual breadboard:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Perhaps a sketch of how you want this to work would help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [slip ring](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/736/1528-1152-ND/5353612?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla5353612&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvuDPBRDnARIsAGhuAmYOq0gzXt8EcodIORUehgytgkN1unnlQCDc6hYsDe9yT1z73TL8pzoaAgeXEALw_wcB)?

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Probably it is good idea to add a rough sketch. I will do that. @Ron No I have already looked into but the budget for the rotator is less. I will add a rough sketch where you will get some ideas. Thanks for both

Comment: Please add hyperlinks to datasheets in your question so we don't all have to look for them.

Comment: Thanks, Transistor. I've tried to add a schematic with block diagram. But it is asking for membership. Let me check is there any free circuit simulator by that I can paste here.

Comment: @Trevor is that block diagram makes sense?

Comment: @Transistor I have added a rough block diagram and hyperlink for datasheet. Could you pls help me with this?

Comment: @Transistor I've ordered components and I am going to try the solution you provided below as well tomorrow.

Comment: @Transistor It would be a great help if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dhinesh: (1) I have already helped you. You are on your own now. My answer is an untested suggestion. (2) You thank afterwards on this site by accepting and upvoting answers.

Comment: @transistor thanks and I will test tomorrow. Definitely I will upvote answers if it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, here is one.

The trick with this one is to send the power and ground through the two wires and modulate the 12V to encode the STEP and DIR signals onto the 12V line. In the schematic below the top part is your transmitter. Note you need the 12V rail and the 5V rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKP1j6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The STEP signal turns the 12V on and off. If the DIR line is low the 5V line takes over for the 12V, if DIR is high the output will be open.

[image]

The receiver, shown at the bottom of the schematic, rectifies the signal and regulates it to your required 5V.

At the same time the level is compared against reference voltages created from the regulated 5V to extract the STEP and DIR levels. D3, R6 and C3 delay the STEP signal a little to ensure the DIR signal has sufficient setup time before the rising edge.

[image]

Considerations: The values shown were calculated and simulated for 1kHz step rate. Faster step rates may run into timing issues that prevent this circuit from functioning. It is also important to keep the STEP signal low for more than about 60% of the time in order for the PWM effect not to starve the regulator. Note though, holding STEP high will actually turn off the stepper eventually.

**ADDITION**

If you do not need the DIR line it is a bit simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkau0A.png)</sup>

In this version I changed the driver side a little to get rid of the invertor gate. The receiver now is just a simple voltage divider and Schmidt Trigger invertor.

The STEP line should be normally low and only pulsed high for 20-30us or so.

[image]

When STEP is low, M1 is on sending 12V to the motor board which charges C1 and lets the regulator power your motor driver. When STEP_IN goes high, M1 turns off and the 12V is cut. The receiver, brings the 12V line down to logic levels via R4 and R5 and D2 makes sure that division never goes over 4.7V. The Schmidt trigger invertor then goes high when the 12V it turned off.

EDIT

Here is a better version, faster modulation and less ripple on the 5V.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68397/discussion-on-answer-by-trevor-mount-360-degree-rotator-with-camera-using-2-pins).

Comment: hi Trevor, this is the place where I really need help! I would like to find out whether I am doing correct way to calculate the base resistor value. This time I made some research and not want to pick the random values as per your suggestion which is good for me to learn.
I've used Ib=Ic/hFE to calculate my base current (i know the load current is 100mA and the hFE is 100 so the Ib is 1mA). So R=(V-Vbe)/Ib= (1.8-0.85)/.001=950 ohm (1K). The value calculated is correct? please guide me. Sorry to bother you

Comment: @Dhinesh yes your math is correct, and the value sounds reasonable, though 100mA in the collector seems a tad high.

Comment: 1. But the datasheet says max 200mA. Do you think it is a good idea to change it to the high-value transistor? 2. Schmitt trigger inverter is generating 34MHZ frequency on the oscilloscope. 3. I have changed the value of R4 to 18K and R5 to 3.3k to get 1.8V at the step out but I am still getting 5V step out.

Comment: @Dhinesh MAX is MAX, design to use what you need to make it work reliably. Otherwise you are just wasting power and will have hotter components and a shorter service life. The transistors, other than the MOSFET should all be operating under 10mA for something like this. Maybe even less if you can tolerate the switching time of the MOSFET.

Comment: Really sorry the meaning of the above statement is that the power consumption is around 100mA. So I can stick with the same transistor. But I can monitor the total power consumption. 2. Could you please answer me why the R4 and R5 doesn't produce 1.8V ?

Comment: @Dhinesh of you want 1.8V you would need to make R4/R5 like 10.2K and 1.8K respectively. It's just a resistor divider. You can go a little higher with the 10.2 if you need to.

Comment: the reason is I don't have 1.8K and 10.2k so I have used 18K and 3.3k. I am confused here, the calculation should be 1.8V right? or my calculation is wrong?

Comment: @Dhinesh 1.86V @ 12V with 18K over 3.3, sure that should work. D1 should really be chosen to limit the voltage under 1.8V though if you can find a 1.8V zener. Why are you using 1.8V though... the DRV8834 is not 1.8V compatible. Are you not using 5V over there?

Comment: it is a good catch but Couple of doubts 1. Don't need to be 1.8V but just wondering I have already driven the motor using the same pulse before.

Comment: @Dhinesh just because you got away with it, doesn't mean you are doing it right. You always need to operate devices at their recommended rating values if you want it to "always" work. ANyhoos, this is getting to be a service call and you have run out of free credit ;) Good luck.

Comment: yes you are right. I will change it. Could you please help me with this. I have noticed earlier that there is a current consumption of  100mA when there is no pulse. I would like to make some changes on the first part of the circuit that if there is no pulse then it should not consumes any power. How to avoid this current consumption. Because the rotator is mounted on the camera and it should consume power only when there is a input pulse. Is there any way I can control the current consumption only when the step pulse is high. As it will help battery to stay long. Suggestions needed pls

Comment: @Dhinesh get rid of R6, increase R2, use small signal N-Mosfets instead of the BJTs.

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I am really sorry to bother you. A couple of things I don't understand and I am really struggling to get step output pulse. See the first image attached for reference- I've fed the 5V step output into the inverter, it gets an inverted couple of times but I am not getting the 5V step output pulse and the output step pulse always stays high at 5V (whether a pulse is there or not?). See the second image for the oscilloscope result. 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVeMs.png 2.https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHiVw.jpg Could you please help me if there is any mistake out of my knowledge.

Comment: I've measured the frequency of the step pulse is 133Hz (7.5ms.) it doesn't sound right for me. is that step pulse slow? You have mentioned earlier step pulse has to be in 20-30us and  1khz range right? is that coding has to be changed? I really don't understand how this one works? Could you please able to assist me?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thsUi.jpg I've managed to modify the code to 20us and frequency nearer to 1khz but still I can't see the step output. your assistance would be great at this point.

Comment: Hi, Trevor sorry to bother you. I am really struggling to find out the fault. Could you please quickly able to guide me seeing the top oscilloscope images I've sent to? It is a much-needed help. Please help me Thanks

Comment: @Dhinesh looking at your scope you only have an under 1.5V signal going into the invertor, it should be 0-5V. Change the resistances back to what I originally showed you.

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back. I've changed the R1=10K, R4=4.7K and R5=3.3K as I don't have exact 7K and 5K. Even though it is not pulsing. Two things I've noticed 1. The voltage gets drop to 3.8V after the zener diode so the inverter is seeing 3.8V always. 2.I've checked at the Q2 collector it is producing 12v step output pulse. but I don't see any pulse on the modulated line from the transmitter.

Comment: @Dhinesh what device are you using?

Comment: are you asking about microcontroller or oscilloscope? I am using ODROID xu4 as a microcontroller and Gwinsteck GDS_1072A-U

Comment: @Dhinesh No the invertor you show in your image.. seriously dude, this is not rocket-science

Comment: sorry, SN74HC14N

Comment: @Dhinesh Does the transmitter work without the receiver attached? If so, are you sure the diode is in D2 is in right. It may need to be replaced with a less leaky one. Use general rule of debug, isolate sections, see which parts work, then see what is affecting what.

Comment: This is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBJVd.jpg I have seen on the M1 drain without the receiver part attached while pulsing

Comment: @Dhinesh I thought you had that working already???? Seriously dude, what do you expect me to do from half a world away.. You have to figure it out yourself. If you cant get this simple thing to work, you will never get the stepper driver to work.

Comment: @Dhinesh you are also asking a lot of a breadboard for this. Any loose connections can cause you all kinds of grief. Better to build it on something soldered like a proto board https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=x%2fXXopaU&id=4F338B66CCCC5F8C845AA05128F54A5BF72C96CB&thid=OIP.x_XXopaUzJb5Ed6Jbre2DQEgDY&q=protoboard&simid=608028381558869682&selectedIndex=17&ajaxhist=0

Comment: oh no Sorry to really bother you.I thought the top part of the circuit was working and generating an output pulse at the drain by changing the MOSFET M1 to IRF9Z14PBF but it is not. I am getting output pulse on the gate but not on the drain. Let me figure it out using veroboard. Thanks

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbIUq.jpg. I have managed to make the transmitter to work see above link. But as soon as I plug the transmitter part to the receiver part (which is to D1 and R4) the pulse disappears and stays at 12V. Meanwhile, I have debugged step by step pulse disappear from the transmitter part once it is connected.

Comment: @Dhinesh there is not much there to stop it... try with JUST the R4 side, that is leave the D4 and the regulator out for now.

Comment: Yes, I've tried only connecting R4 section I am getting a 12V low pulse. Let me check the connection at the R4 section because it is not producing any 5V.

Comment: @Dhinesh I really suspect  your diode is not.. well.. dioding

Comment: yes, you are right without the D2 I am getting a 1.8v low pulse at the output. Can I use 1N750 diode? where Id is 2uA. I need to look into R4 and R5 as well.

Comment: @Dhinesh The diode needs to be your basic rectifier diode. I think the one you have is letting the 12V from the cap back into the line, which is really floating when the pulse is low, and pulled low by R4 and R5.

Comment: I have understood that by changing the D1 as basic rectifying diode will stop the 12v coming from cap which means it doesn’t float and pulled low when the pulse is low?

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I've ordered 1n4001 basic rectifying diode as a replacement for D1(1N5817). Do you think do I need to change the D2 (1N4732A Zener diode as well?)

Comment: I am having a doubt, I've built a circuit in Veroboard. I am getting a 5V low pulse at the output stage without connecting regulator circuit and Schmitt inverter. But as soon as I connect the 4.7V Zener diode the pulse gets to drop down to 3.8V where the inverter doesn't read the pulse. 1. Why is the pulse dropping? 2. Why can't we use 5.1V Zener diode by that the inverter sees 5V pulse? If I am wrong pls forgive me.

Comment: Hi, Trevor, the motor is working. Thanks for your help and great support. I've learned a lot how to analyse the circuit and build a prototype. Still, something I've to verify. Thanks

Comment: @Dhinesh :) Good to hear, thanks for letting me know. Not many folks do and I always wonder how they got on.

Comment: Hi, Trevor sorry to bother you. Just noticed there is a small issue with the little current consumption of 40mA when there is no pulse on the circuit even after changing small signal Mosfet(BS170), get rid for R6 and I've increased the value of R2 to 47K. I really would like to know how this works? is the gate threshold voltage of BS170 is high? what I have to look here? Could you please guide me here. I am happy to understand here

Comment: @Dhinesh can you add your latest schematic for me to see. Also, how much of that is the 5V regulator and stepper motor driver consuming.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzvVB.png 20mA for regulator and 20mA for the motor. I am using Pololu D24V50F5 as a regulator now but I may change to Pololu S7V7F5

Comment: @Dhinesh ok, you can increase R3 considerable, assuming you watch the fall time on the signal. There is a trade off there, the bigger you make R3 the wider the step pulse needs to be. R4 and R5 can also be larger, and they will affect the fall time. Some tuning is required here. BTW I would reduce R1 to 50-100ohms. It will not affect the current consumption, but will cause M3 to turn on and off faster.

Comment: @Dhinesh also, if you are just stepping the motor to a position and keeping it there, keeping the motor active all the time will drain current when you do not need to. There is, I am sure, a way to make the driver go into a low power mode when it is just sitting there.

Comment: Basically making the step pulse wider using increasing R3. I will do the changes now. I've noticed that there is a enable pin to disable driver but the problem may be a holding torque. I don't know I need to check.

Comment: @Dhinesh it depends if you are micro-stepping or not. If not it is pretty easy to add a circuit to reduce the holding current to something trivial. Unfortunately, the SLEEP pin resets the current position.

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I am using 1/4-step mode. Yes, sleep pin resets. Here is the image attached to values changed R3-47K  R1-100ohm and R7 and R5 7K and 5k respectively. Could you please guide me here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK0vU.png

Comment: @Dhinesh not you used MOSFETS you can put R6 back in.

Comment: I am using mosfet

Comment: @Dhinesh yes I know, that's why it is now ok to put R6 back in. It wont gobble current with MOSFETS like it did with the BJTs.

Comment: Current drawn has been reduced to 10mA but I don’t read any pulse at the first mosfet drain itself. Where I am making mistake?

Comment: @Dhinesh assuming you did not zap a mosfet, I have no idea.. Is there still a signal on the gate of M3..

Comment: No there is no signal on m3. I’ve changed both the mosfet in case I might have damaged but still there is no signal and stay at 12v. But there is a input pulse of 1.8v appears on the gate.

Comment: @Dhinesh 1.8V is really too low for those MOSFETs. I assume it is 1.8V on the other side of R1 too.

Comment: yes you are right. Do you think bss138 logic level mosfet would be suitable? I have used before for 1.8V or TN0702?

Comment: TN0702 would be better. Note the BS170 is fine for M4.

Comment: Ok, I will order TN0702.

Comment: @Dhinesh or you could put the NPN back in where M3 is.

Comment: yes I will do and let you know

Comment: Fig 1 output from NPN transistor https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOOz2.png and Fig 2 output from NPN Mosfet https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyfum.png.

Comment: I don't see any pulse on the M1 drain. is that because it is not seeing any square pulse? could you please clarify. I am really learning every day.

Comment: @Dhinesh R3 is too large

Comment: I've changed to 27K but I am getting a sharp pulse.

Comment: @Dhinesh the gate of M1 turns off when the voltage stored on it's capacitance decays through R3. As such R3 needs to be small enough to let that happen quickly. I have no idea what you mean by "I've changed to 27K but I am getting a sharp pulse." The pictures help a lot.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjUsk.jpg This is the rough diagram I have seen from the oscilloscope for every 1.8v pulse I was getting a 5v sharp pulse like the image. Sorry for the image as I am in train.

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I have changed the R3=10k now the motor is running but there is tiny current consumption of 10mA.

Comment: @Dhinesh :) Nice Good work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think using a Mosfet will eliminate that 10mA?

Comment: @Dhinesh we have reduced the circuit pretty much as best you can now. My 2nd circuit is probably a little less wasteful, but not a lot. Now you need to look at which part is consuming most of that 10mA. I'm guessing the stepper driver.

Comment: oh ok. when I connect the motor to the driver then it consumes 10mA. Is there any other way I could control that using enable line without affecting the holding torque?

Comment: @Dhinesh no. But that is not the right question. The right question is, do I need to hold it with so much torque when I am not stepping.

Comment: sorry Yes, you are right. I can check that practically by mounting the camera.

Comment: @Dhinesh note if you were full stepping you would not need to use ANY current to hold.. Assuming the camera isn't a wind vane.

Comment: @Dhinesh anyhoos, If you can drop the holding current that would be pretty easy to do.

Comment: @Dhinesh but you should make that a new question. I have to step out for most of the  day.. so have fun ;)

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think I am going to use full step. So definitely there should be a way to drop the holding current. No problem. Let me check and I will let you know. If not I will post another question. Great thanks for your help so far. You made me love electronics.

Comment: It seems like holding torque is not a problem. But I am still looking into that. meanwhile, I've got a question why don't I toggle enable line to turn on/off the driver within the circuit?

Comment: Hi, Trevor, I've found that the holding current cannot be dropped using DRV8834. are there any suggestions on the circuit to enable and disable the enable pin using a transistor? Will that possible? I can do that modification in the circuit and implement.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5UkmH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Stealing power from the STEP and DIR lines.*

Figure 1 shows one *slight* possibility that I have never seen used.

- The STEP and DIR signals need to be boosted to provide enough current and voltage to drive the motor.
- D1 - 4 tap off and rectify the signals to provide power for the chip and motor.
- The STEP and DIR signals are optimised to maximise the time when the signals are at opposite logic levels. i.e., When DIR is low the STEP should have a high mark-space ratio. When DIR is high then STEP should have a low mark-space ratio.
- C2 is intended to hold maintain the voltage between DIR and GND in the times when STEP and DIR are at the same level. (These times are kept short by the micro-controller code.) Without it there would be no ground reference for the input signals.

One big problem with this is that the signal received by the STEP and DIR inputs will exceed that of the chip - both positive and negative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUiTk.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A pair of transistor drivers buffer the over-voltage STEP and DIR signals to the motor driver.*

Figure 2 is an attempt to address this problem.

Comment: +1 but that's really three lines... don't forget ground.

Comment: Also, why is the 100uF cap on the DIR line

Comment: Ahh @Trevor! I didn't explain adequately although I did explain what C2 was for. There is no GND connection. I'll see if I can do a better job.

Comment: OH.. appologies, I did not recognize it as a full bridge.. my bad.

Comment: Still... I think the 4.7mF cap would handle the both high or low transistions pretty well.

Comment: It's just that when both lines go high or both go low the controller inputs are undefined. C2 is intended to hold the ground referenced for some time. I have no idea if it would work.

Comment: Yes I see your point. hmmm

Comment: @Transistor the above schematic looks simple and easy to understand but it is very hard to modify the schematic as per my requirement. Sorry to bother you. I really don't know how to do that. is there any suggestion you can give me by that I can modify the schematic and upload it to verify with you to eliminate direction line and convert it to a ground line? And use only step line as 12V or 5V and ground. Giving me suggestions helps me a lot.